# Disable display output signal from USB-C port

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, external-display, displayport, usb-c

I want to disable USB-C port for exernal display output signal and instead only use the HDMI as display port.
I have USB-C connection from laptop to a screen/display, purely for the reason to provide power to the laptop battery, and  also have HDMI for display/sound signal. But USB-C does transmit monitor signal to my screen whether i like it or not, and so my laptop registers 2 displays. How can i disable USB-C port as a display port and only use it as power port, when in my home office, but going back to default when i'm anywhere else?

I have my reasons why i prefer to use HDMI.
Hope my question is clear.
My laptop is a Lenovo thinkpad X1 carbon

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings-> Display -> Advanced display settings - select the display you want to disable (usually the 3rd one) and on the bottom you would find a toggle for "Prevent win for using this display". Enjoy!